# Like Operator in Sub Query SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-like

I have a query with a sub query embedded in it. I would like to use the `like` operator and not the `IN` operator. The `IN` operator works fine, but doesn't give me all the results I need...

I have tried the below query, but get :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

**Query :**

```
SELECT a.Name, 
  CONVERT(nvarchar(50),RTRIM(b.[num])) + ' - ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50),b.name) AS 'My Code'
FROM firstTable a 
left join secondTable b ON (a.id = b.id)
WHERE a.Name like (select RTRIM(LTRIM('%' + [Customer_Name] + '%')) FROM thirdTable)
```

Comment: you could join on thirdTable with the same like, that way you can see which records are double. Or if you only care about the first occurence, the subquery can use a top 1 `... like (select top 1 rtrim...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query, but since this is join using `LIKE` operator the performance might be not very good:

```
SELECT a.Name, CONVERT(nvarchar(50),RTRIM(b.[num])) + ' - ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50),b.name) AS 'My Code'
 FROM firstTable a 
     left join secondTable b ON (a.id = b.id)
     INNER JOIN thirdTable c ON a.Name LIKE '%' + c.[Customer_Name] + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `in` for a partial match, but you can use `like` in the `on` clause.
Try this:

```
SELECT a.Name, 
  CONVERT(nvarchar(50),RTRIM(b.[num])) + ' - ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50),b.name) AS 'My Code'
FROM firstTable a 
Inner join third table on a.name like rtrim(ltrim('%'+ customer_name +'%'))
left join secondTable b ON (a.id = b.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

this will return multiple records which is not satisfy be the query

```
WHERE a.Name like (select RTRIM(LTRIM('%' + [Customer_Name] + '%')) FROM thirdTable)
```

instead of that you can use

```
SELECT a.Name, CONVERT(nvarchar(50),RTRIM(b.[num])) + ' - ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50),b.name) AS 'My Code'
 FROM firstTable a 
     left join secondTable b ON (a.id = b.id)
     INNER JOIN thirdTable c ON a.Name LIKE '%' + c.[Customer_Name] + '%'
```

OR

```
SELECT a.Name, 
  CONVERT(nvarchar(50),RTRIM(b.[num])) + ' - ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50),b.name) AS 'My Code'
FROM firstTable a 
left join secondTable b ON (a.id = b.id)
WHERE a.Name like (select RTRIM(LTRIM('%' + c.[Customer_Name] + '%')) FROM thirdTable c where c.id = @id)
```

OR

```
SELECT a.Name, 
  CONVERT(nvarchar(50),RTRIM(b.[num])) + ' - ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50),b.name) AS 'My Code'
FROM firstTable a 
left join secondTable b ON (a.id = b.id)
WHERE a.Name like (select top 1 RTRIM(LTRIM('%' + [Customer_Name] + '%')) FROM thirdTable)
```